# MonoGame 3D - Triangles aren't visible when center Y < about -2.0

Tags: 3d, xna, monogame

I have a small code base, and you can see the full code at [my current commit on GitHub](https://github.com/cable729/Mezzola/tree/548258ea9625e661c85e6210fec16cfe48e17686). I will try to put the relevant code in here. Basically, if I move a triangle's `Position`, which changes the World matrix, it becomes invisible. Any ideas?

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;

this.vertices = new[]
{
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), color),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), color),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), color)
};

this.effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
            device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.001f, 50.0f);
this.effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Vector3.Down, Vector3.Forward);
this.effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(entity.Position);

foreach (var pass in this.effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    this.device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, this.vertices,
        0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being that my far clip was too close to where I was drawing the triangles (I was drawing ON the far clip).

Simple!